# Protect a given Laravel route with htaccess password

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, routes, .htpasswd

Is it possible to protect one!! laravel route with htaccess password?

I have a migrator route and that one should be accessed with a htaccess password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Laravel HTTP Basic Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#http-basic-authentication) to protect a route in a simple way:

```
Route::get('your-route', function () {
   // Only authenticated users may enter...
})->middleware('auth.basic');
```

Please note that, by default, this technique uses email and  password stored in 'users'  table to give access to an user.